# How to calculate flux at a specific frequency from another frequency and spectral index

Tags: radio, flux

First of all, I know spectral index is $\alpha=\frac{log\frac{S_1}{S_2}}{log\frac{v_1}{v_2}}$ where $s$ are the flux densities and $v$ is the frequencies. I wonder that If i can use spectral index and an flux density observation to calculate other? Basically i know that the spectrum follows power law spectrum where I want to make this calculation (GHz radio frequencies), it almost fits the power law.

Comment: If it fits almost a power law, you can almost apply that power law to get the flux at different frequencies. Do it, but be aware and discuss the uncertainties and limitations. You can do anything, if you have good enough justification. (NB: For that reason, the oral examp of a PhD often is called "defence": You defend and justify and have to convice others of proper scrutiny and correct application of knowledge of the methods of what you have been doing :) )

Comment: Can you put an appropriate title that reflects the body of the post? We know you have questions on this topic.